# How to make function run every time page refreshes in meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

i have the following code:

```
Template.home.onRendered(function() {
        var scrollElem = $("#scroll");
        scrollElem.scrollTo("max", 500);
})
```

I'm also using jquery-scrollto package for meteor. It fires only once when page is loaded but when i refresh it never fires again. I know that onRendered runs only when element is changed but what should i use then? I tried to put this code in Meteor.startup() and $(window).load() but it doesn't work either.
I fixed it by adding `setTimeout()` function but what if user's internet connection is slow? It wont fire. Any solutions for this?

Comment: For jQuery, it's `$(window).load()` rather than `$(window).onload()`. You could try using that or, if you don't need to wait for things like images to load, you could try using `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Code in `onRendered` *should* run after a browser refresh. What kind of "refresh" are we talking about here?

Comment: Of a page refresh. I also tried $(document).ready() and it doesn't work

Comment: using the refresh button in your browser?

Comment: If you `console.log('test')` in your `onRendered` function, does it print "test" in the console after that refresh?

Comment: Yes. It shows "test" every time after refresh. Hmmm

Comment: Okay... then scrollElem probably hasn't loaded yet or something. [It does seem a little outdated](https://github.com/nate-strauser/meteor-jquery.scrollTo/) (last commit in February 2014)

Comment: I fixed it by adding setTimeout function. Thanks

Comment: But what if user's internet connection is slow? it wont fire unless timeout is about 10 seconds. Any solutions?

Comment: Yeah, don't rely on `setTimeout` for this. Let's find a better solution. Maybe rewrite your question to refocus the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If not already doing so, try using [the newer version of the package](https://atmospherejs.com/johnantoni/meteor-scrollto).

It may be that your `#scroll` element is not loaded yet. You could try using the `load()` method:

```
Template.home.onRendered(function() {
        var scrollElem = $("#scroll");
        scrollElem.load(function () {
          scrollElem.scrollTo("max", 500);
        });
})
```

If it still does not work, try using the plugin directly instead of using a purely intermediary meteor package. Uninstall the package:

```
meteor remove johnantoni:meteor-scrollto
```

In your head code, for example **client/main.html**:

```
<head>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.scrollto/2.1.0/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Or, if you want to keep the lib in your app, [download it](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo/master/jquery.scrollTo.min.js) and put it in **public/jquery-scrollto/**, then in the head:

```
<head>
  <script src="/jquery-scrollto/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: i tried everything you offered and it's not working :\ 'load()' method is not working even with 'setTimeout()' also. Sad